# how to escape % (percent sign) in Hive QL?

Tags: escaping, hive

I need my filter to retrieve rows which contain values `CPU usage %` and also `% usage` as follows:

where m.CounterName like `%CPU usage \%` or `m.CounterName` like `\%usage%`.

The backslash works for `CPU usage %` but not `% usage`

How do I escape `%` sign ...when the `%` is at beginning of the string I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As is also stated in https://dwgeek.com/apache-hive-like-statement-pattern-matching-example.html/

the expression below should work:

```
like '\% usage%'
```

meaning any string the begins with "% usage".